# How to pass iterators to parameters correctly (C++)?

Tags: c++

Below is the delete function for a hash table that uses separate-chaining.

This is working code and searches within the delete function.

```
        void delete_elem(int value)
        {
            list<int> ::iterator itr;
            int hashedIndex = hashFunction(value);

            for (itr = myTable[hashedIndex].begin();
                    itr != myTable[hashedIndex].end(); itr++)
            {
                if (*itr == value)
                {
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (itr != myTable[hashedIndex].end())
            {
                myTable[hashedIndex].erase(itr);
            }
            else
            {
                cout << value << " was not found" << endl;
            }
        }
```

but this version doesn't work and uses a helper function to do the searching.

```
        void delete_elem(int value)
        {   
            // auxiliary iterator        
            list<int> ::iterator tmp;

            if (search(value, tmp))
            {
                int hashedIndex = hashFunction(value);

                cout << "here3" << endl;
                myTable[hashedIndex].erase(tmp); // this line segfaults
                cout << "here4" << endl;
            }
            else
            {
                cout << value << " was not found" << endl;
            }
        }

        bool search(int value, list<int> ::iterator tmp)
        {
            int hashedIndex = hashFunction(value);

            for (list<int> ::iterator itr = myTable[hashedIndex].begin();
                    itr != myTable[hashedIndex].end(); itr++)
            {
                if (*itr == value)
                {
                    tmp = itr;
                    cout << "tmp: " << *tmp << "\n"; // outputs an int, which is fine
                    cout << "itr: " << *itr << "\n"; // outputs the same int, which is fine
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    tmp = myTable[hashedIndex].end();
                }
            }

            return tmp != myTable[hashedIndex].end();
        }
```

Somehow the tmp in my delete_elem() wasn't affected by the search(). How can I change this?

UPDATE (fixed by passing the iterator to the search function as a reference, and just realizing that iterators are NOT pointers in C++, but use pointer-like syntax):

```
void delete_elem(int value)
        {            
            list<int> ::iterator tmp;
            if (search(value, &tmp)) // passed in tmp as an address
            {
                int hashedIndex = hashFunction(value);

                cout << "here3" << endl;
                myTable[hashedIndex].erase(tmp);
                cout << "here4" << endl;
            }
            else
            {
                cout << value << " was not found" << endl;
            }
        }

        bool search(int value, list<int> ::iterator *tmp)
        {
            int hashedIndex = hashFunction(value);

            for (list<int> ::iterator itr = myTable[hashedIndex].begin();
                    itr != myTable[hashedIndex].end(); itr++)
            {
                if (*itr == value)
                {
                    *tmp = itr; // edited
                    cout << "tmp: " << *(*tmp) << "\n"; // edited
                    cout << "itr: " << *itr << "\n"; // edited
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    *tmp = myTable[hashedIndex].end(); // edited
                }
            }

            return *tmp != myTable[hashedIndex].end(); // edited
        }
```

Comment: pass `tmp` as reference.

Comment: or better return it from `search`

Comment: It worked. Thanks! Typical pass by reference issue.

Comment: not really typical, because it isnt clear why you pass `tmp` as parameter in the first place. `search` should return it instead. The caller can compare it with `end` to know if the value was found (compare to `std::find`)

Comment: okie dokie. Thanks for the advice.

Comment: i flagged as duplicate of a pass-by-value vs pass-by-reference Q&A. Btw please do not edit the answer into the question. Answers should go to answers, while questions are for the questions